# nested dict entries update simultaneously

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have an experiment to run with a bunch of parameters to handle, each one taking all possible values from a respective list, and two numbers as a result for each set of parameters. I decided to create a nested dictionary created by the following code

```
import functools
def lists_to_dict(ls, d):
    def list_to_dict(l, d):
        return dict(zip(l, [d for _ in range(0, len(l))]))
foldr = lambda func, xs, acc: functools.reduce(lambda x, y: func(y, x), xs[::-1], acc)
return foldr(lambda l_, d_: list_to_dict(l_,d_), ls, d)
```

where the foldr function just handles the recursion part

For example,

```
ex = lists_to_dict([[1,2],[3,4]],0)
print(ex)
```

returns

```
{1: {3: 0, 4: 0}, 2: {3: 0, 4: 0}}
```

which is precisely what I want. However, when I update one entry at the innermost level, all corresponding entries update the same. For example

```
ex[1][3] = 1
print(ex)
```

returns

```
{1: {3: 1, 4: 0}, 2: {3: 1, 4: 0}}
```

i.e. ex[key][3] = 1 for all keys at the first level.

Why is that so a how can I build a nested dict like that while having

```
ex[1][3] = 1
print(ex)
```

return

```
{1: {3: 1, 4: 0}, 2: {3: 0, 4: 0}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a dictionary is an object in python and lists store references to that object. So

`[d for _ in range(0, len(l))]` stores `l` references to the same dictionary. Copies of the dictionary can be created with copy() method:

```
import functools
def lists_to_dict(ls, d):
    def list_to_dict(l, d):
        if isinstance(d, dict):
            return dict(zip(l, [d.copy() for _ in range(0, len(l))]))
        else:
            return dict(zip(l, [d for _ in range(0, len(l))]))
    
    foldr = lambda func, xs, acc: functools.reduce(lambda x, y: func(y, x), xs[::-1], acc)
    return foldr(lambda l_, d_: list_to_dict(l_,d_), ls, d)
```

Now it works like you want:

```
    ex = lists_to_dict([[1,2], [3,4]],0)
    ex[1][3] = 1
    ex
{1: {3: 1, 4: 0}, 2: {3: 0, 4: 0}}
```